# "Cannot connect to appcenter.ms" in IOS build from the app center

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-app-center

I am not able to download the iOS app from the app center.
It was working previously now i am getting error "Cannot connect to appcenter.ms"

Comment: post logs from AppCenter, post the code which you use to connect to App Center. It used work? Maybe it was working in debug and not in release?

Comment: I'm sure this is just a typo - but "Cannot connect to appcenter.cs" should be "Cannot connect to appcenter.ms"?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: Apologies for typo error. it is  appcenter.ms